How can I return the first element in an Object array and convert it to String in Swift?
I'm trying to make a card game and want to return the card on the top of the deck. Here's the creation of the deck:
struct Card{
    let val: String
    let suit: String
}

class Deck{
    var cards: [Card] = []
    
    init(){
        let vals = ["2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K","A"]
        let suits = ["Spades","Clubs","Hearts","Diamonds"]
        
        for suit in suits{
            for val in vals{
                cards.append(Card(val:val, suit:suit))
            }
        }
    }

I've created a getFirstCard function:
func getFirstCard() -> Card{
        return cards.removeFirst()
    }

While this works, it returns the Card object:
Card(val: "2", suit: "Spades")

My problem is that I'd like it to return as a string of "number + suit", so in this case, "2Spades". I've also tried returning Card.val and Card.suit only to get syntax errors. So how can I convert this into a String?

Your func getFirstCard() deletes the first card and returns it, it does notget
the first card. To get the first card use cards.first. To return this as a String
as you described, use this function in your class Deck:
 func getFirstCardAsString() -> String {
     if let firstCard = cards.first {
         return firstCard.val + firstCard.suit
     }
     return ""
 }

EDIT-1:
alternative approach to get the card as String
struct Card {
    let val: String
    let suit: String
    
    func asString() -> String {  // <--- here
        self.val + self.suit
    }
}

and use it like this:
 let deck = Deck()
 let card = deck.getFirstCard()
 print("----> card: \(card.asString())")


That did work, thank you. Technically I do still want to delete the first card because in a real game of cards the top card is “deleted” from the deck since it is dealt to a player, but I’ll implement that later. Thanks again.

ok, see my updated answer (EDIT-1) for an alternative way of getting any card as a String.

In addition to writing your own string representation function, you might use a computed property. And maybe conform to CustomStringConvertible, too:
extension Card: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String { "\(rank)\(suit)" } // personally, I would do "\(rank) of \(suit)", but this is up to you
}

Then you can just:
let card = deck.getFirstCard()
print(card)                      // you can just `print` directly
print("Your card is \(card)")    // or you can use string interpolation

(Forgive the edit to your type, but I think “rank” is a more customary term for a card value, rather than “val” or “value”.)

A few unrelated observations:

I know you asked for a string like “2Spades”, but you might contemplate other string representations, too. In a UI, we might expect to see “2 of Spades”. Or, if looking a poker range charts, a two character abbreviations are very common, too, e.g. “2S” for two of spades, “TC” for ten of clubs, “QD” for queen of diamonds, etc. This abbreviated format also affords more compact representations of a hand of cards, e.g., the “dead man’s hand” of a pair of black 8’s and a pair of black aces is 8C-8S-AC-AS (with an unknown hole card).

I might define the ranks and suits as enumerations. Then you can do things like:
struct Card {
    let rank: Rank
    let suit: Suit
}

And if those enumerations were CaseIterable, you could do things like:
class Deck {
    var cards: [Card]

    init() {
        cards = []
        cards.reserveCapacity(52)

        for suit in Card.Suit.allCases {
            for rank in Card.Rank.allCases {
                cards.append(Card(rank: rank, suit: suit))
            }
        }
    }
}

The Deck type really shouldn’t be worrying about the internal representation of ranks and suits. Furthermore, the enumeration protects you from an error, where you might have thought that the queen was represented by “Q” in one place and a “q” or “Queen” elsewhere. Enumerations allow the compiler ensure that a consistent set of values is used throughout the codebase.
As a very, very minor point, but I have omitted the default value in the cards property declaration and put it in the initializer. This pattern is useful because you might have an init(from:) for decoding, and you don’t ever want to set the value of cards twice.

I might suggest that the name getFirstCard does not clearly represent the notion that you are not only returning the card, but also removing it from the Deck. I might suggest a name like drawCard, which clearly suggests that you are drawing a card from the deck (both returning the drawn card, but removing it from the deck).
func drawCard() -> Card? {
    if cards.isEmpty { return nil }

    return cards.removeFirst()
}

I would also make it return an optional, so it gracefully handles an empty deck. That way you can do things like:
var deck = Deck()

while let card = deck.drawCard() {
    print(card)
}


You made Card a value type, but Deck a reference type. Personally, I would make Deck a struct, too.

FWIW, I believe that “new deck order” is often:

Ace through King of Hearts
Ace through King of Clubs
King through Ace of Diamonds
King through Ace of Spades

There might be other orders, too, but, I believe this is a common “new deck order”. And, it is out of scope here, but a new deck also includes two advertisement cards at the start and two jokers at the end.



FWIW, here is a rendition that captures the above points:
// MARK: - Card

struct Card {
    let rank: Rank
    let suit: Suit
}

extension Card: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String { "\(rank)\(suit)" } // personally, I would do "\(rank) of \(suit)", but this is up to you
}

extension Card {
    var localizedDescription: String {
        "\(rank.localizedDescription) of \(suit.localizedDescription)"
    }
    
    var abbreviation: String {
        "\(rank.abbreviation)\(suit.abbreviation)"
    }
}

// MARK: - Array<Card>

extension Array where Element == Card {
    static var allCards: [Card] {
        var cards: [Card] = []
        cards.reserveCapacity(52)
        
        for suit in [Card.Suit.hearts, Card.Suit.clubs] {
            cards += Card.Rank.allCases.map {
                Card(rank: $0, suit: suit)
            }
        }
        
        for suit in [Card.Suit.diamonds, Card.Suit.spades] {
            cards += Card.Rank.allCases.reversed().map {
                Card(rank: $0, suit: suit)
            }
        }
        
        return cards
    }
}

// MARK: - Card.Suit

extension Card: Codable {
    enum Suit: String, CaseIterable, Codable {
        case spades
        case hearts
        case diamonds
        case clubs
    }
}

extension Card.Suit: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .spades: "Spades"
        case .hearts: "Hearts"
        case .diamonds: "Diamonds"
        case .clubs: "Clubs"
        }
    }
}

extension Card.Suit {
    var abbreviation: String {
        return switch self {
        case .spades:   "S"
        case .hearts:   "H"
        case .diamonds: "D"
        case .clubs:    "C"            
        }
    }
    
    var localizedDescription: String {
        NSLocalizedString(description, comment: "Card.Suit")
    }
}

// MARK: - Card.Rank

extension Card {
    enum Rank: String, CaseIterable, Codable {
        case ace   = "A" // or you could use "ace"
        case two   = "2"
        case three = "3"
        case four  = "4"
        case five  = "5"
        case six   = "6"
        case seven = "7"
        case eight = "8"
        case nine  = "9"
        case ten   = "T" // or you could use "10"
        case jack  = "J" // or you could use "jack"
        case queen = "Q" // or you could use "queen"
        case king  = "K" // or you could use "king"
    }
}

extension Card.Rank: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        return switch self {
        case .ten:   "10"
        case .jack:  "Jack"
        case .queen: "Queen"
        case .king:  "King"
        case .ace:   "Ace"
        default: rawValue
        }
    }
}

extension Card.Rank {
    var abbreviation: String {
        rawValue
    }
    
    var localizedDescription: String {
        NSLocalizedString(description, comment: "Card.Rank")
    }
}

extension Card.Rank: Comparable {
    var value: Int {
        return switch self {
        case .two:   2
        case .three: 3
        case .four:  4
        case .five:  5
        case .six:   6
        case .seven: 7
        case .eight: 8
        case .nine:  9
        case .ten:   10
        case .jack:  11
        case .queen: 12
        case .king:  13
        case .ace:   14
        }
    }
    
    static func < (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        lhs.value < rhs.value
    }
}

// MARK: - Deck

struct Deck: Codable {
    var cards: [Card]
    
    init(cards: [Card] = .allCards) {
        self.cards = cards
    }
    
    init(from decoder: any Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        cards = try values.decode([Card].self, forKey: .cards)
    }
}

extension Deck {
    mutating func drawCard() -> Card? {
        if cards.isEmpty { return nil }
        
        return cards.removeFirst()
    }
}

There are tons of variations on the theme, but hopefully this illustrates the idea. I also (a) added Codable conformance; and (b) laid the groundwork for localized string representations (for the UI), but that’s not terribly relevant here.
